# In Mongoid, are there any differences in the Date, Time, DateTime, and TimeWithZone field types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

The documentation mentions the four types of time related field types (http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields). In other databases, I can see how these fields are going to be difference types in the database but for MongoDB aren't they all going to be Date types? Is this just for consistency with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are almost no difference between them, all of them wrap Time type.
You can change DateTime, Date or TimeWithZone to get instances of this types after unserializing from mongo.

Mongoid extends this classes to add demongoize/mongoize methods for data binding. So the only difference is in implementation.

So Time implementation

```
def demongoize(object)
  return nil if object.blank?
  object = object.getlocal unless Mongoid::Config.use_utc?
  if Mongoid::Config.use_activesupport_time_zone?
    object = object.in_time_zone(Mongoid.time_zone)
  end
  object
end

def mongoize(object)
  return nil if object.blank?
  begin
    time = object.__mongoize_time__
    if object.respond_to?(:sec_fraction)
      ::Time.at(time.to_i, object.sec_fraction * 10**6).utc
    elsif time.respond_to?(:subsec)
      ::Time.at(time.to_i, time.subsec * 10**6).utc
    else
      ::Time.at(time.to_i, time.usec).utc
    end
  rescue ArgumentError
    EPOCH
  end
end
```

Date implementation

```
def demongoize(object)
  ::Date.new(object.year, object.month, object.day) if object
end


def mongoize(object)
  unless object.blank?
    begin
      time = object.__mongoize_time__
      ::Time.utc(time.year, time.month, time.day)
    rescue ArgumentError
      EPOCH
    end
  end
end
```

You can check other implemetations

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/extensions/date.rb#L46
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/extensions/date_time.rb#L49
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/extensions/time.rb#L48
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/extensions/time_with_zone.rb#L32

UPD:

sorry links are outdated since they are pointed to master branch

Comment: Just a warning : I've observed a strange bug in rspec tests, where assertions on DateTime fields would sometimes fail because of a millisecond difference. I don't have this problem with Time types or when systematically reloading an object before assertion.

Comment: This answer is not true in Mongoid 6.2. Mongoid's `Time` data type serves for storing `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, whereas `DateTime` is a pure Ruby `DateTime`. And there are important differences between these two.